# Pythonic version of loop

Tags: python, loops

I am writing a loop to make an API call in other to retrieve financial time series data between 2 dates. Given the API limitations i have to make a series of small date intervals and use a loop to make a sequence of calls. I was able to do it using the following loop :

```
#create a datelist index of smaller intervals

start_date = dtm.datetime(2014,1,1)
end_date = dtm.datetime.now()
datelist = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='M')
start_date = datelist[-1].date() +dtm.timedelta(days=1)
datelist.append(pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D'))

#get the intial and next date on the list convert to UNIX format and pass the interval on the API call

for n in range(len(datelist)-1):
    indateunix = tm.mktime(datelist[n].timetuple())
    enddateunix = tm.mktime(datelist[n + 1].timetuple())
    templist = self._api_call.returnChartData(ticker= 'FB', period='D',start=indateunix, end=enddateunix)
    arr = arr + templist
```

I imagine this is not the best way to do it, is there any pythonic version for the same loop ?

Answer (score -1):

use `zip`:

```
for indate, enddate in zip(datelist, datelist[1:]):
    indateunix = tm.mktime(indate.timetuple())
    enddateunix = tm.mktime(enddate.timetuple())
    ...
```